# Custom UITable & set scroll window

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, Header and Footer. The header and footer are rounded, but the rows show behind the table. How can I set the scroll window to only be inside the area under the header and top of the footer.

Header and footer have transparent backgrounds.

See pictures below[image: Snap shot of the table...extends past the header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are using a header for the section which is floating above it's rows.

What you should do is add your "header" to the top of the UIView instead of having it as a section header, this will keep the "Recent Deposits" image statically at the top and your rows won't float under it.

Comment: Yeah answer makes total sense. Having issues forwarding the Delegates through my custom TableView however... But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to redraw header/footer -- remove transparent area/fill with some color